# VS 2017: Add reference from solution in remote repo (without downloading the solution)

Tags: c#, reference, visual-studio-2017

I want to add references of projects, existing in github (without cloning those solutions) to my solution's projects. 
Is there a way to do this? 
These solutions were not published as nuget packages and I do not want to download them as I just want to reuse some pieces of code.

Comment: No, there is no way of referencing things without downloading them, unless it is a web service of some kind.

Comment: if you need to add project reference, you need the project as part of the solution. if you need to add assembly reference, you need to have the assembly available to you (as a nuget package or by compiling the project). either way, you need to download the project first

Comment: Thank you, guys!